# How to permanently exclude a folder (and sub-folders/files) from windows 7 jumplists?

Tags: windows-7, privacy, jumplist

From what I read, it's not a built-in feature, so what's your workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [windows seven forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/99487-how-exclude-files-folders-recent-lists-jump-lists.html):

> It's possible to turn off the recent items
>   in the jumplists of specific programs.
>   But it's a laborious process. I will
>   describe it, but you'll have to do the
>   legwork.
>
> The Jump lists for each program are
>   stored in
>
> C:\Users(User
>   name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
>
> as automaticDestination-ms files with
>   random names.
>
> To figure out which file belongs to
>   which program , you'll have to do some
>   detective work.
>
> For instance, you could open a video
>   with your media player program.
>
> Change the AutomaticDestinations
>   folder into Detail view and Sort by
>   Date Modified.
>
> Only one or two of the files should be
>   showing as modified in the past
>   minute. One may be a list of recently
>   viewed folders, the other should be
>   your program.
>
> Delete one of the files then try to
>   open your program's jump list. If it
>   is gone, you have the right file.
>
> Once you have identified the right
>   file, restore it from recycle bin and
>   set the file properties to Read-only.
>   This will disable the jump list for
>   that file. You'll need to do this for
>   all the programs you want to exclude
>   from jump lists.
>
> As you can see, this would be a long
>   and lengthy process, you'd be better
>   off creating a password protected
>   user. Good luck.
>
> A Guy

I hope that helps!

Comment: Now if only it were possible to exclude specific items (e.g., files, folders, drives, network locations) from being listed… `:-ʃ`